# How to insert the value of a javascript variable into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, applet

I have an applet in my php file.I will get a value from the applet,into a javascript variable( score from the applet)
i want to insert the value into database.So i think i should use ajax.But the users can see the javascript codes.

Users should not insert the value their own by just calling the javascript function(where the ajax codes written) from the inspect element's console or any other way.

How can i do this?

```
  if(window.document.drops.isFinished()){
       score=window.document.drops.getScore();
       updateScore(score);//ajax codes written in this function
       return;
   }
```

Comment: Using javascript variable in db is the same as using user input, you cannot prevent users to see/manipulate it. You can only filter it

Comment: my problem is that if the user called the method updateScore(10000),Then value will be inserted in the database..i should prevent that

Comment: send the value to php, not to javascript then

Comment: can you give me the code to send the value to php

Comment: I assume you are talking about java applet, so check this out: http://www.coderblog.de/sending-data-from-java-to-php-via-a-post-request/

Answer (score 0):

The score should be stored on the server side from the get go. This is because there is no way to ensure that your client side code has not been tampered with. The data stored on your server **should** be able to help you preserve the integrity of your game. Without giving us more details about your applet etc, there's not a lot of advice that people can give you.

Comment: How can i store the score on the server side..Now it is in the javascript variable

Comment: How did you end up with storing it in js

Comment: rest will do by the function updateScore();In updateScore() function it will pass the value to a php file.But if the user called the same method same thing will happen

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches to realise this:

- [Indexed Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-IndexedDB-20130704/)
- [Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)
- [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Besides the fact of security issues.